# octave saveas undefined

Tags: linux, matlab, plot, gnuplot, octave

I have an octave code

```
M = csvread('result.csv');
h=hist(M);
saveas(h,'hist.jpg');
```

I got error message
     error: `saveas' undefined near line 11 column 1

I remember I did use saveas before. How come it is "undefined", my current octave version is

$ octave -version
GNU Octave, version 3.2.4
Copyright (C) 2009 John W. Eaton and others.

I just want to save a plot to an image file. Besides "saveas", do I have any other options?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here is an example: https://saturnapi.com/fullstack/plotting-square-and-sawtooth-in-octave

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the command `print`, as

```
print(h,'name',['format']);
```

[Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html) is the complete reference.